# Does 4 Ezra (2 Esdras) teach the divinity of Ezra?

Tags: ezra, apocrypha, pseudepigrapha, 2esdras

<sub>The following question has been initially posted [by user44810 on Judaism.SE](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126119), where it was closed for lying outside the community's defined scope.</sub>

---

In an [article](http://otp.wp.st-andrews.ac.uk/abstracts-lectures/the-book-of-6-ezra-2-esdras-15-16) by the [University of St. Andrews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_St_Andrews) about the Book of 4 Ezra, it is stated:

> In the Syriac text of 4 Ezra 14:48 (and the versions that derive from it) there is a brief account of the ascent and apotheosis of Ezra which is missing in the Latin of [2 Esdras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Esdras).

I am currently trying to find out where this is found. The only place in 4 Ezra where I could find anything similar to this is 4 Ezra 2:42-48

> <sub>I Esdras saw upon the mount Sion a great people, whom I could not number, and they all praised the Lord with songs. And in the midst of them there was a young man of a high stature, taller than all the rest, and upon every one of their heads he set crowns, and was more exalted; which I marvelled at greatly. So I asked the angel, and said, Sir, what are these? He answered and said unto me, These be they that have put off the mortal clothing, and put on the immortal, and have confessed the name of God: now are they crowned, and receive palms. Then said I unto the angel, What young person is it that crowneth them, and giveth them palms in their hands? So he answered and said unto me, It is the Son of God, whom they have confessed in the world. Then began I greatly to commend them that stood so stiffly for the name of the Lord. Then the angel said unto me, Go thy way, and tell my people what manner of things, and how great wonders of the Lord thy God, thou hast seen.</sub>

**Is this the account of the ascent and apotheosis of Ezra, or is the article speaking about something else ?**

Comment: While Im not Yet familiar with this passage.
I like 2nd Esdras though I've only read the missing leaf from second book of Esdras (or, 4 Ezra). Chapter seven verses 75-105. Known as "The Missing Fragment" Read that here: https://www.therain.org/studies/esdras.html The Masoretic text reference Four books of Ezra. I believe they could be it. And Perhaps should never have been taken out of The Bible. The Puritans removed whats now known as the Apocryphal books from The 1611 King James Bible. Here is a digital scan of the first edition Original KJV 1611.
https://bibles-online.net/1611/ I recommend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the account of the ascent and apotheosis of Ezra ?

No, it is not; as the first quote explicitly states, the passage in question *is missing in the Latin of 2 Esdras*, which is where your last quote comes from; thus, it cannot be that.

> Is the article speaking about something else ?

Yes, it is; specifically, it is referring to the following passage, contained in [the footnote to the respective verse](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2_Esdras_14:44-48&version=NRSV&interface=print) from the [New Revised Standard Version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Revised_Standard_Version):

> [The] Syr[iac version] adds *in the seventh year of the sixth week, five thousand years and three months and twelve days after creation. At that time Ezra was caught up, and taken to the place of those who are like him, after he had written all these things. And he was called the scribe of the knowledge of the Most High for ever and ever*. Ethiop[ian,] Arab[ic,] 1 Arm[enian versions] have a similar ending.

And now, to finally address the title's main question:

> Does 4 Ezra (2 Esdras) teach the divinity of Ezra ?

No, because, in traditional Christianity, the term [apotheosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apotheosis#Christianity) carries a different connotation than in Greek paganism (Genesis 1:26-27).